# 変数の中身が勝手に空になる

Tags: bash

以下のシェルスクリプトを実行すると、gitのcheckoutまではうまくいくんですけど、以降のcdとechoがうまくいきません。DirectoryNameが空文字で何も表示されません。なぜでしょうか？

```sh
#! /bin/bash

echo "put the directory name :"
read DirectoryName
cp -r base "./$DirectoryName"
git checkout -b $DirectoryName
cd "`pwd`/$DirectoryName"　#　ここから$DirectoryNameが空になってる
echo "`ls | grep $DirectoryName` directory and branch is created!"
```

Comment: 挙動が「cd がエラーを出す」ではなくて「何も表示されない」のであれば、cd で失敗しているのではなくて echo で失敗している可能性は無いでしょうか？　cd によって `./$DirectoryName` に移動しているので、そこで `$DirectoryName` という名前のフォルダを探そうとしても見つからなさそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さんありがとうございます。ECHOに関してはその通りでした！しかし、cd自体が機能してないですよね。移動しないです。

Comment: 変数をエコーに直接渡したら、ちゃんと値が出力されました。変数が空になっているわけではないようです。このスクリプトを実行した後にecho $DirectoryNameを実行しても表示されなかったので、空になったと勘違いしていました。（スクリプト中変数の値は失われいているわけではなく、その後端末でechoしても出力されていないだけでした。）なぜcdがうまくいかないのかはわかりません。。

Comment: もしかして、このシェルスクリプトをシェルから実行した後に、そのシェルにおいてディレクトリが移動していないことを「cd がうまくいかない」と表現されていますか？　それは仕様通りの挙動なので、cd は上手くいっていそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu その通りです。これは、仕様通りの挙動だったのですね。。スクリプト実行したら変わるかと思ってました。。manで確認します。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  別のプロセスが立ち上がり、そのプロセスのほうでcdが行われてるのですね。変数ももう一方のプロセスで定義されていて、手元のほうでは、見れないのですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 変数は空になっていません。何かしらの挙動を見て変数が空になっていると勘違いなさっているようです。
- `cd` コマンドによって `./$DirectoryName` に移動した上で `ls | grep $DirectoryName` をなさっているので、この結果は殆どの場合空になり、空文字が出力されそうです。
- もしこのシェルスクリプトを `test.sh` みたいなファイルに保存してシェルから `./test.sh` みたいに実行してもカレントディレクトリが `./$DirectoryName` にならないことをもって「`cd` がうまくいかない」と表現されているのであれば、これは間違いです。`./test.sh` のように実行したときにはシェルの上で新しくシェルが立ち上がっており、その中で `cd` され、新しい方のシェルが終了することによって元のシェルに戻ってきます。したがって元のシェルでは `cd` されません。元のシェルで `cd` されるようにするには、実行側でシェルビルトインコマンドの `source` もしくは `.` を使う必要があります: https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1712/21/news015.html

  - あるいはファイルにシェルスクリプトを保存することに拘らないのであれば、`~/.bashrc` で関数として定義してしまうというやり方もあります。

ついでに、`` echo "`ls | grep $DirectoryName` directory and branch is created!" `` の部分は単に `echo "$DirectoryName directory and branch is created!"` で良さそうですね。`cd` の部分も `pwd` を使う必要は無さそうでした。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。grepのほうは確かにpathがおかしいですね。このスクリプトを実行したときに、別のプロセスが立ち上がり、その立ち上がったプロセスのほうで変数が定義されているから、手元の端末で,echoしても変数の中身が見れなかったんですね。関数にしてしまうのはとても勉強になりました。

Comment: ああ、なるほど！　その挙動をもって空だと判断されていたのですね。全くそのとおりで、実行した側のシェルでは `$DirectoryName` は定義されないので参照もできません。